# It possible to have subscript and super script that does not shrink the font size?

Tags: fontsize, subscripts, superscripts

It possible to have subscript and super script that does not shrink the font size?

Usually the font size becomes smaller: e.g. [image]

Is it possible to have the subscript and superscript in normal font size?

Comment: Do you want that just for the one-off formula or generically, for any formula in your text?

Comment: Generically: I'm using a very verbose subscript and superscript. I'm afraid that it becomes unreadable if it shrinks.

Comment: See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-mathsize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just the one-off case, you can

```
\[ x^x x^{\displaystyle x} \]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you also know the command for the other styles? Other than \displaystyle?

Comment: Yep... `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want this behavior everywhere:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathSizes{10}{10}{10}{10}

\begin{document}
$a_{b_{c}}\quad x^{x^{x}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]